# Wpf Style Trigger triggered only once

Tags: c#, wpf

I have added a property trigger on a grid as below

```xaml
<Grid.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
        <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value=""></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding StoredValue}"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Grid.Style>
```

The property is triggered only once when I hover over the grid.
What I require is that the property's (`StoredValue`) getter has to be called every time when MouseHover happens.

Please help

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried setting IsMouseOver = False also but it does not seem to work

Comment: It's unclear from your question what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: The binding property's getter is only called once when the grid is rendered and MouseHover happens for first time.
The Subsequent MouseHover's do not initiate the getter again. If the getter is triggered again i will get the updated value.
Hope i am more clear this time

Comment: You should probably implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and fire the PropertyChanged event when StoredValue changes.

Comment: Show us the code for `StoredValue` please.

Comment: public string StoredValue => AnotherClass.SomeMethod();

Since the property is dependent upon some method is another class INotifyPropertyChanged does not help me here. Only when the SomeMethod is called it will get the updated value. Thus i need to trigger whenever MouseHover happens. This StoredValue property is present in the ViewModel

Comment: @SagarDeshpande so the result of `AnotherClass.SomeMethod()` changes based on the users mouse position? (I hope not)

Comment: Do u want to show ToolTip on `Grid` or `GridCells`. You shall directly bind ToolTip to GridCell

Comment: Not dependent on mouse position. Just that mouse hover should trigger my getter

Comment: GauravKP it does not matter actually to me ,I have only one row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to update the tooltip every time it is displayed, you can utilize the `ToolTipOpening` event to refresh the binding:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid1" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding StoredValue,TargetNullValue=''}"/>
            <EventSetter Event="ToolTipOpening" Handler="grid1_ToolTipOpening"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
</Grid>
```

Update the binding in code behind:

```
private void grid1_ToolTipOpening(object sender, ToolTipEventArgs e)
{
    var s = sender as FrameworkElement;
    var be = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpressionBase(s, FrameworkElement.ToolTipProperty);
    if (be != null)
    {
        be.UpdateTarget();
    }
}
```

Note: the `TargetNullValue=''` is necessary in case `StoredValue` would sometimes return a `null`. Otherwise the Tooltip wouldn't attempt to open and thus the `ToolTipOpening` would never happen and the value would never update from the `null` to a new value.

Comment: `ToolTipOpening` seems like an ideal event to update tooltip.

Comment: It may perhaps also be sufficient to drop the entire Binding, and directly assign the ToolTip property in the event handler. Something like `s.ToolTip = ((VM)s.DataContext).StoredValue;`

Comment: @Clemens without an initial tooltip value, the tooltip will never attempt to open ;) however, the initial value could be anything, no matter the binding

Comment: @Clemens Ouch, this actually exposed a weak point of my approach: if `StoredValue` is null at any point, the tooltip will stop opening

Comment: TargetNullValue

Comment: I am following the MVVM pattern here. So I would need to translate the code behind code to the ViewModel i.e the tooltip event to be handled in ViewModel.

Comment: @SagarDeshpande if you want to update only on opening, this is a view related decision and should be handled in view even when using MVVM. If you have a logic / viewmodel related update reason, use `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Ok Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

While I can't explain the nature of problem, here is a quick workaround: rise notification manually, then binding will refresh itself. You trade trigger for event:

```
<Grid Background="Transparent" MouseEnter="Grid_MouseEnter">
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
            <!-- normal binding, this line is comment and should be gray -->
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding StoredValue}" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
</Grid>


public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string StoredValue => "123"; // is called every time mouse is entered

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // rise notification manually
    void Grid_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(StoredValue)));

}
```

Comment: The nature of problem is that the Binding in the Style setter is reused. Since there was no change notification for the source property, the Binding isn't reevaluated and simply produces the current source property value.

Comment: @Clemens, I noticed that, thanks. Perhaps you knows a better solution to said problem? Is there a way to force reevaluation? By changing complete style in the trigger?